# Give an ID to select menu when append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having this

```
<script id="produstTypes" type="text/template">
   <select name="selectMenuProducts">
     <option value="ch0021">Chair</option>
   </select>
</script>
```

I use it multiple times to create the same select menu.

```
var product.append(
    $('<label>Products</label>')
);

product.append($($('#produstTypes').html()).change(function(){ //how do I give an ID to "selectMenuProducts"?
    //do stuff
});
```

How can I give an ID to `name="selectMenuProducts"` when append()?

Comment: Ermm I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do but like this? `$('select[name="selectMenuProducts"]').attr('id','enterYourIDHere');`

Comment: What is `product` you need to show more code! And it's quite unclear what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Protip: If you're going to add multiple instances, use classes, not id's. This prevents conficts and bugs.

Comment: @sourRaspberri. Thanks. Where should I give the ID?

Comment: @Patrick2607 Thanks. I know. But in this case ID's are essential as each dropdown controls different DIVs on the page.

Comment: well I'm not sure why you would want to add an ID to the element seeing as you can select it another way. If you want to add an ID then anywhere you want? :S

Comment: @sourRaspberri thanks :)